# Need help reading from a txt file in C

Tags: c, matrix, io

I am working on a project in C which requires me to read in matrix values from a txt file. The first two lines are the number of rows and columns, and the rest is the actual matrix data.

For example, something like this:

```
2
2
1.0 2.0
3.0 4.0
```

The code I wrote is giving me some issues. Here's a snippet:

```
matrix read(char* file){

 FILE *fp;
 printf("check 1\n");
 fp = fopen(file,"r");
 printf("file opened\n");

 // Make the new matrix
 matrix result;
 printf("matrix created\n");

 int counter = 0;
 int i;
 int j;
 int holdRows;
 int holdColumns;


 if(counter == 0)
 {          // read in rows
            fscanf(fp, "%li", holdRows);
            printf("here is holdRows: %li\n", holdRows);
            counter++;
 }
 if(counter == 1)
 {          // read in columns
            fscanf(fp, "%li", holdColumns);
            printf("here is holdColumns: %li\n", holdColumns);
            counter++;
            // Now that I know the dimensions, make the matrix
            result = newMatrix(holdRows, holdColumns);
 }
 // For the rest, read in the values
 for(i = 0; i < holdRows; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < holdColumns; j++)
             fscanf(fp, "%lf", &result->matrixData[i][j]);


 fclose(fp);
 return result;
}
```

Whenever I run this, holdRows and holdColumns are not the values stored in the txt file. For example, I tried a 3X4 matrix, and it read that there was one row and three columns.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you have `counter` and these `if`s with `counter`?

Comment: Same as above.....the counter variable seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: @pmg: please don't tag a question as homework unless you have "proof" that it is, and since the OP hasn't answered the question (note: he doesn't have to answer) you have no way of knowing.

Comment: You aren't checking the return status from fscanf() - so you don't know if anything is being read from the file.

Comment: `%li` is not a valid scanf conversion specifier for `int`. It's for `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to suggestions by you all and some sleuth work myself, I solved my problem. First, I was entering the wrong filename (well, now I feel silly), and second, I was reading the data in as the wrong type.

Thanks, everyone, for your help!

Comment: @user411313: passing a local variable works in general, returning the address of a local variable is the broken concept.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the address of holdRows and holdColumns to `fscanf`. You have to change them to `fscanf(fp, "%li", &holdRows);` and `fscanf(fp, "%li", &holdColumns);`.

Comment: I switched to &holdRows and &holdColumns, but the data read in is still incorrect. Thanks, though :)

Answer (score 0):

the `%li` conversion specification requires a `long*` as matching argument to `fscanf()`: you're passing a `int` (`int*` after correction proposed by dbarbosa).

Try `"%i"` ... and same for `printf()`.

---

The `%lf` expects a `double`. Is `matrix` made of doubles?

Comment: Yes, matrix is made of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
 for(i = 0; i < holdRows; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < holdColumns; j++)
             fscanf(fp, "%lf", &result->matrixData[i][j]);
```

with

```
 double temp;
 for(i = 0; i < holdRows; i++)
       for(j = 0; j < holdColumns; j++) {
             fscanf(fp, "%lf", &temp);
             result->matrixData[i][j] = temp;
       }
```

I seem to recall that in C some types of 2D arrays don't play nice with &.

Comment: That might work, but I'm not sure, since I'm still reading in incorrect values for holdRows and holdColumns, and holdColumns is in the 7 digits, so the loop goes on for a very long time.

Comment: @buzzbuzz: test the return value of `scanf` and exit the loop early if there's an error